# How can i add the abstract and acknowledgment on the same page?

Tags: page-breaking, abstract

I want to add my abstract and acknowledgment on the same page as they only fill the half of the page in total, so it looks foolish to have them split into two pages.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openbib]{report}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
 This is cool paper about vuvuzelas.
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
 Thanks Mum!
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

This method creates two pages, how do i add them together in one page instead?

Comment: Which documentclass are you using? Can you turn your snippet into a complete example? Edit: Personally, I would keep them in separate pages I think.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., normally i would separate them as well, but the content is so thin that it would look quite stupid, maybe i'm overthinking it? Its `report` and i'm writing up my thesis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `abstract` will call the `titlepage` environment.  You can patch it to not do that and then place the two "abstracts" in one title page:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\abstract}{\titlepage}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\endabstract}{\endtitlepage}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  \begin{abstract}
    This is cool paper about vuvuzelas.
  \end{abstract}

  \renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
  \begin{abstract}
    Thanks Mum!
  \end{abstract}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Report` class uses `\titlepage` in the beginning of `environment{abstract}` and `\endtitlepage` in the ending of environment{abstract}. You can use `\let\titlepage\relax` and `\let\endtitlepage\relax`. Reference, similar question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209065/to-have-no-pagebreak-after-include-in-latex). `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` is to define to start and stop the `relax`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openbib]{report}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\let\endtitlepage\relax
\let\vfil\relax
\begin{abstract}
 This is cool paper about vuvuzelas.
\end{abstract}
\let\titlepage\relax
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Acknowledgements}
\begin{abstract}
 Thanks Mum!
\end{abstract}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]